# Как починить админку в Yii?

Tags: php, yii

Добрый день. Возникла проблема с входом в админку на Yii
Структура следующая

```
app/
     /framework
     /protected
          /admin
               /controllers (для админки)
               /modules
               ...
          /controllers
          /modules
          ...
index,php
admin.php
```

Файл index.php

```
<?php
$yii             = dirname(__FILE__) . '/framework/yiilite.php';
$frontendConfig  = dirname(__FILE__) . '/protected/config/frontend.php';

defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);
defined('YII_TRACE_LEVEL') or define('YII_TRACE_LEVEL', 3);

require_once($yii);
Yii::createWebApplication($frontendConfig)->run();
```

Файл admin.php

```
<?php
$yii           = dirname(__FILE__) . '/framework/yii.php';
$backendConfig = dirname(__FILE__) . '/protected/admin/config/backend.php';

defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', false);
defined('YII_TRACE_LEVEL') or define('YII_TRACE_LEVEL', 3);

require_once($yii);
Yii::createWebApplication($backendConfig)->run();
```

.htaccess

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^admin admin.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . index.php

#ours develop ip 
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^77\.47\.225\.88
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^46\.219\.23\.82
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^46\.219\.23\.77
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^91\.214\.84\.194
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^178\.140\.85\.203
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^85\.10\.200\.59
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^77\.47\.130\.186
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://blago-vest.org/

php_value error_reporting 1

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1 [R=301,L] 


#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
#RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} 
php_value error_reporting 1
```

Не работает ни site.ru/admin, ни site.ru/admin.php ни site.ru/admin/user/login На все получаю 404 ошибку

Comment: Судя из htaccess - верный урл site.ru/admin, для того-что понять откуда 404 ошибка, надо глянуть лог приложения /protected/runtime.

Comment: Вся правда в логах

Comment: И еще конфиги надо привести для Yii `/protected/admin/config/backend.php`

Answer (score 1):

Вообще очень странная структура. Тут либо надо админку в модуль выносить, либо директорию admin выносить на 2 уровня вверх рядом с app. И еще лучше веб директорию на уровень вниз опустить. Например мне кажется вот такая структура безопаснее:

```
htdocs/
    .htaccess
    index.php
    ...
protected/
    controller/
    module/
       admin/
       ...
    ...
vendor/
    yii/
    ...
```